# Having just one instance of Gmail inbox filtered in particular way in a single tab

Tags: gmail

Is there some way so that one can have a dedicated tab in the Chrome browser filtering my Gmail messages in a certain way (e.g., "is:starred in:inbox")?

In all the options I saw, I can only find the "multiple inboxes" feature, but that lumps all of the inbox instances in the same tab and this is very distracting.

Comment: yes, now it is much more clear, thanks a lot. by the way, I do not understand why the downvotes

Comment: They probably came from the fact that the question was unclear in its prior state.

Comment: Open a new tab in chrome, search messages as required, then pin that tab maybe? I think the new messages arriving and matching that search criteria will appear.

Answer (score 4):

Gmail search terms are added to the URL, so you can easily have a dedicated URL that you can bookmark to bring you to what you want.

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/is%3Astarred+in%3Ainbox
```

This will bring you straight to Gmail with the default logged in user with the search for starred conversations in your inbox already entered. Chrome will easily allow you to have one tab with your search already run and another with just "normal" Gmail.